# Kali Linux no space left and updated , did not update full and now stuck in log in screen cant get passed

Tags: linux, command-line, kali-linux, dual-boot

I am having a problem but with dual boot kali and windows. when I want to add more to the partition with gparted it does not allow me to add more unallocated space to the Linux space provided? And I cannot get passed the log in screen too aswell as I had updated the new Linux which I shouldn't have done and did not fully complete the update due to not having enough space... now it does not let me get passed log in or can't add more allocated space to the Linux file what to do Is there a fix for this? It's dual booted not virtual machine
would appreciate immensely some assistance

Comment: Best bet would be to boot a live cd image and mount the filled up volume to clear up some space.

Comment: Boot Live cd of the gparted or the dual boot kali linux? And how is that done by mounting the filled up volume as I cannot log in to the linux at all my question is different as to the other one previously as I am in a boot loop because I had not updated properly nor , does it let me allocate more space

Comment: Is there anywhere I can contact you? I've reached out to people and they haven't been able to help me ... Kindest Regards man

Comment: It is assumed that you are very familiar with Linux as Kali is [explicitly](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) designed for use by Linux experts. With such strong skills in Linux, you should be able to boot a Linux live cd image and clean the kruft out of you installation disk. Can you detail the problems you're having that go beyond the normal boot and clean sequence?

Comment: Hey yeah it's true I'm a beginner user for kali linux only realising later on with better research that it is for more experienced users , after I had dual booted it so on and so forth I just need to gain some files once I get into it again and download a more normal linux . Well I had updated the kali linux without having enough storage space allocated. So now when I want to log in it just puts me right back to the log in screen although my log In is correct... the update didn't seem to have properly update which is causing this . Also which linux a kali linux iso on usb ? Could I contact ?

Comment: Would appreciate it because I've tried gparted and it does not allow me to shrink the main os storage and add to the partition of the linux. It says operation failed also

Comment: The problem is that I never had enough storage inside the partition aswell as not being used to the Linux as a whole . The more I research the more I realised it is not very beginner friendly which I realised later.  I have got the live boot but when wanting to change the files on the partition it does not let me . It says their is no such thing of the name or he cannot be found inside of the interactive shell command in the rescue mode . But I am yet to even fix it . As it still does not let me inside of the os I just want to get some files out of the os and I will think about other os to use

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be with the size of your partitions or your RAM. Linux is very picky with how you resize it and your login issues are probably due to low storage space on your computer.

As a user said in the comments, your best bet is to use a live USB or CD boot. Remember to download the authentic ISO's from [the official website](https://kali.org). On the download page, you will see a live boot ISO for x86-64 and ARM. Download this one, the rest will try permanent installation and will write on the disk.  Do not trust third parties.

There are tutorials on how to flash USB's with Etcher and Rufus and the steps are already on Stack Exchange and Youtube. Again, download from official sources. ([Rufus](https://rufus.ie), [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/))

Live ISO's do not write to the disk. All data is handled with RAM for programs. With Swap space built in, this shouldn't be a problem unless your computer has low specs. I am not aware if changes persist by storing data on the USB but Kali is used for penetration testing, not for family photos.

If you still insist on permanent installation, try to clear your drive of unnecessary programs, games, or other miscellaneous content.

Comment: Yeah well that's the problem I was a beginner of even linux os. So yeah I realised later. How do I even fix this their wasn't much to do when getting in to os when it had not much space while updating and then when I went back into it was mentioning kernel panic of some sort

Comment: I have got it in a live USB and the partition that the dual boot is on I have , gone to the interactive shell but it does not allow to do anything with it, says something along the line of the host name could not be found . So as of right now I am unable to make any changes for the dual boot with the live boot . Looking for someone to try tell me how to remove the unnecessary files or even the latest update on the kali linux. I might just delete the whole thing anyways and use something more beginner friendly to be honest